# SonarQube 5.1 - Gradle sonarRunner task - Unable to find referenced rule BooleanInversion; perhaps the rule name is mispelled?

Tags: sonarqube, profile, illegalargumentexception, rule, sonarqube5.1

I have SonarQube 5.1 version, Jenkins 1.628 and Gradle 2.3

I was able to run successful Gradle build (including Unit tests) + nonUnit tests (behind Tomcat) + getting combined code coverage and publishing of all the data to SonarQube server until yesterday I went to SonarQube and added a new manual rule "Create Manual Rule". It's under Rules > Button "Create Manual Rule".

After the rule was created, I was able to see the new rule in the Search box (left top corner). The next thing I did was to ACTIVATE that new manual rule (under Bulk Change button at top right corner) in **SonarWay - Java** Profile to find out what it'd do. It didn't error out anything and it successfully updated something/profile.

After doing that, when I ran the analysis (using Gradle's sonarRunner task), it's failing with the following error. Even though I deleted that manual rule, I'm still getting the same error. Seems like I missed to deactivate the rule first from SonarWay Java profile (default) before deleting the rule.

Any idea how can I resolve the following error and still use **SonarWay Java** profile (under Quality Profiles) in SonarQube for analyzing a java project?

(PS: As a workaround, I have set the default profile for Java (Java profiles) to one of the FindBubgs profile which comes and error is gone for now).

```
17:37:50 22:44:12.571 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.4.0 done: 509 ms
17:37:50 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:37:50 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
17:37:50 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:37:50 Total time: 11.169s
17:37:50 Final Memory: 39M/2027M
17:37:50 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:37:50 ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
17:37:50 ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
17:37:50 ERROR: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find referenced rule BooleanInversion; perhaps the rule name is mispelled?
17:37:50 ERROR: Caused by: Unable to find referenced rule BooleanInversion; perhaps the rule name is mispelled?
17:37:50 ERROR: 
17:37:50 ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
17:37:50 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
17:37:50 :sonarRunner FAILED
17:37:50 
17:37:50 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
17:37:50 
17:37:50 * What went wrong:
17:37:50 Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
17:37:50 > Process 'command '/production/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
17:37:50
```

**Full detailed log is here:**

```
17:44:42 22:51:04.548 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=17ms
17:44:42 22:51:04.548 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor
17:44:42 22:51:04.550 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.4.0...
17:44:42 22:51:04.566 INFO  - Java version: 1.8
17:44:42 22:51:04.616 INFO  - PMD configuration: /production/home/c400093/JSlaves/sagrdev3sb10_1/workspace/TCCProcedureSvc/build/sonar/pmd.xml
17:44:43 22:51:05.161 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.4.0 done: 611 ms
17:44:43 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:44:43 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
17:44:43 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:44:43 Total time: 11.407s
17:44:43 Final Memory: 44M/2002M
17:44:43 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:44:43 ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
17:44:43 ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
17:44:43 ERROR: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find referenced rule BooleanInversion; perhaps the rule name is mispelled?
17:44:43 ERROR: Caused by: Unable to find referenced rule BooleanInversion; perhaps the rule name is mispelled?
17:44:43 ERROR: 
17:44:43 ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
17:44:43 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
17:44:43 :sonarRunner FAILED
17:44:43 
17:44:43 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
17:44:43 
17:44:43 * What went wrong:
17:44:43 Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
17:44:43 > Process 'command '/production/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
17:44:43 
17:44:43 * Try:
17:44:43 Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
17:44:43 
17:44:43 * Exception is:
17:44:43 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:306)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
17:44:43 Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/production/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
17:44:43    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.sonar.runner.tasks.SonarRunner.run(SonarRunner.java:62)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
17:44:43    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
17:44:43    ... 44 more
17:44:43 
17:44:43 
17:44:43 BUILD FAILED
17:44:43 
17:44:43 Total time: 17.4 secs
17:44:43 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue deactivate PMD rule Boolean Inversion. It seems deprecated in sonarqube 5.1

Comment: I think PMD is successful if you notice the line: 17:37:50 22:44:12.571 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.4.0 done: 509 ms

Comment: PMD is successful but import of PMD results in SonarQube is not.

Comment: Is the /production/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java installed properly? Which version of java is used for sonaqube?

Comment: @R3104d Yes, I do see /production/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java (use it on a daily basis). The same version is getting used to run Gradle's sonarRunner task. Are you saying "PMD plugin" version (in SonarQube 5.1 aka my instance) is not compatible with Java8.x version? I don't think so as it was working for almost 4 months successfully. After I disabled "SonarWay - Profile" and used the other profile (Under Quality), sonarRunner task is working now but what I'm trying to find is, this all happened after I added that "new" manual rule and activated it in "SonarWay - Profile" and since then, I got this.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam, I can try deactivating PMD rule Boolean inversion but still curious why everything was working in SonarWay - Java profile before I added the new "manual" rule and activate that new role in this profile. If you are saying that the issue is only with the PMD rule Boolean inversion, then don't you think it would have failed (sonarRunner task or sonar analysis) earlier (i.e. before I created the manual rule and activated that) as well ?

Comment: Where can I find this setting in SonarQube 5.3 so that I can turn it off? I've searched high and low for it. I've done a full clean and re-run also. Was it or was it not deprecated and when?